# How to get the creation time for each file and format it

Tags: windows, powershell

I can format the time of the files with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem Dropbox | Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
```

I can get the CreationTime of the files with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem Dropbox | Select-Object CreationTime
```

They blow up when I combine them together. How can I get the creation time in a format I desire?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to [expand](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) the `CreationTime` property:

```
Get-ChildItem Dropbox | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationTime | 
  Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"
```